# Presenting Modal View Controller before window is visible

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uiwindow

I would like to present a view controller modally before calling `-makeKeyAndVisible` on the application's window. However, this code only shows the `mainNav` view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *mainNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Restore"]) 
    {
        DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail];

        // changing main to mainNav does not help
        [main presentModalViewController:learnNav animated:NO];

        [detailNav release]; [detail release];

    }

    self.window.rootViewController = mainNav;

    [main release]; [mainNav release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better make the window appear and **then** present the modal view with `animated=NO`. What's the point of presenting the modal view before everything else is instantiated and displayed?

#### Edit

To try to make your code work, here are a couple of hints. Try this:

```
[mainNav presentModalViewController:learnNav animated:NO];
```

or this:

```
[main.navigationController presentModalViewController:learnNav animated:NO];
```

I'd say that these two methods work best if they're put after the `makeKeyAndVisible` call.

Comment: I would like to setup everything before I show anything, otherwise there might be quick changes in the UI that confuse the user. In the `DrillDownSave` example, the window is also only shown in the end. Apart from that, showing the window first does not change anything.

Comment: Please, read the edited answer, and tell me if it works. Thank you!

Comment: No, it does not change anything. But I tried around a bit and it seems you were kind of right: I need to "show" the window before presenting view controllers. I added this line before the `if` statement: `[self.window addSubview:mainNav.view];` and removed `self.window.rootViewController = mainNav;`. Now it works.